# Probability problem without replacement and series

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I have a probability problem but I am unsure about the result.
I would like to confirm my guesses.

During an exam, 10 students are drawing one by one a question (among 12 questions) without putting the question back.

One student did not study 3 questions.

Let x be the number of passage of the student, and p the probability that he draws a question he did not study.

1) Is p independent of x.
2) Is p a decreasing function of x (ie, the more the student waits, the less likely he will draw a question he did not study).

For me:
1) clearly, $p$ is dependent of $x$.

2) My guess is that it has to do with the total probability formula, to get a "sequence", and then, we have to tell if the sequence is increasing or decreasing.

if $x=1$, then $p=3/12$.

if $x=2$, then it depends on what the first student drew.

Let Bi: we draw a "bad" question on the i-th draw.
Let Gi: we draw a "good" question on the i-th draw

We can have either: B1 & B2 or G1 & B2.
So using the total probability formula, we have:
P(B2)= 3/12 * 2/11 + 9/12 * 3/11 = 3/12

Can somebody help to find the more general formula please ?

Fixed: figures in my formula.

Thanks.

Comment: The probability the student will draw a question he did not study is $3/12$, no matter when the student draws the question. This is because all permutations of the questions are equally likely. The probability that the question at position $8$ is bad is just the same as the probability that the question at position $1$, or $9$, is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability the student will draw a question he did not study is $3/12$, no matter when the student draws the question. This is because all permutations of the questions are equally likely. The probability that the question at position $8$ is bad is just the same as the probability that the question at position $1$, or $9$, is bad.

If you have $3$ black balls, and $9$ red, and arrange them at random, any position is just as likely to be occupied by a black ball as any other position.

**Remark:** If the above is not obvious, let us calculate. It is clear that if the student is first, his probability of drawing a bad question is $\frac{3}{12}$.

Let us do a painful cases analysis of the probability the student draws a bad question if he is second.

This could happen in two ways: (i) First question is bad, **and** second question is bad or (ii) First question is good and second is bad.

We first find the probability of (i). The probability first is bad is $\frac{3}{12}$. Given that, the probability second is bad is $\frac{2}{11}$, for a probability of $\frac{3}{12}\cdot \frac{2}{11}$.

Similarly, the probability of (ii) is $\frac{9}{12}\cdot\frac{3}{11}$.

Add. We get $\frac{3}{12}\cdot\frac{2}{11}+\frac{9}{12}\frac{3}{11}$. Simplify. We get $\frac{3}{12}$, the same answer as the one we got the "easy" way above.

Now if you are in a mood to do unpleasant work, you could find  the hard way the probability that the student draws a bad question, given that he is third in line. This can happen in several ways: GGB, GBB, BGB, BBB. Calculate all these probabilities, add them. Again you will get $\frac{3}{12}$.

After that, it is unlikely you will want to calculate the long way the probability given the student is fourth in line!

Comment: André, you're so bright ! In fact, you are right but it was not intuitive to me, that the proba remained the same. I had to kill my head. I fixed an error in my formula and got your result. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: After a while it will be intuitively obvious, this was a good first step. With probability, it takes a while to build up the intuition. Many "reasonable" beliefs turn out to be wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah, in probability beliefs can be your enemy. Am I correct to say here that p is independent from x ?

Comment: Yes, one could. It bothers me a little to say it, because **independent** also has a technical meaning in probability theory, while here it is being used in its everyday sense. I would prefer the wording "does not depend on."